# 3 monitor screen lock, which unlocked, corrupts configuration

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

UDATE #3: This may be a race condition that arises during initialization of my 3 monitor system.  GPT-4 says of the `syslog` displayed at the end, which occurred during a successful attempt to activate the third monitor:

> The log entries indicate that the system was doing some internal GPU
> work. It appears to be setting configurations for different display
> interfaces (DP-0, DP-1, and HDMI-0) and resolutions (@1920x1080 and
> @3840x2160). This is typical in systems with multiple display
> configurations or those that require special graphical settings.
>
> Some information about the devices (max pixel clock, whether they are
> connected or not) is also provided and there are also some entries by
> the RealtimeKit daemon (`rtkit-daemon`), an UNIX daemon that takes
> care of prioritizing and scheduling real-time and time-sensitive
> processes.
>
> Therefore, an interpretation might be, the system is adjusting the resolution of multiple displays attached to it and the RealtimeKit
> daemon is helping coordinate these time-sensitive operations in a safe
> way.

UPDATE#2: I've taken to recovering from this failure mode by unplugging the blanked monitor's HDMI cable and plugging it back in multiple times until the situation corrects itself -- which it seems to eventually do.  I am a bit concerned about wear and tear.

A big concern here is there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of narrowing down which of the many moving parts are the right place to lodge a bug report.

UPDATE#1 The following screenshot is the most frequent failure mode following return from screen lock:
[image]
But I seem to be able to recover my configuration if I power the system off in order to restart it.

Original:

When i leave my 3-monitor computer long enough for my monitors to blank, when I then press a key to log in, the only monitor that i can use is the smallest one.  The other two remain off.  When I log back in, and the desktop reappears on the smaller monitor but the two larger monitors remain off.  When I right click to discover what has happened, it is impossible to properly get back my 3 monitor configuration, so i have to power off and restart the computer.  When it comes back, all my web browser windows are on the smallest monitor although the other two monitors have come back.  I must then rearrange my desk top, moving my browser windows to the larger monitors and expanding the browser windows.

Also, note the screenshot says "No proprietary drivers are in use." [image: note the screenshot says "No proprietary drivers are in use.]
This is 22.04.2 LTS with nvidia driver metapackage 525 (proprietary) NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Ti]

One problem, but not the ultimate cause of the Title's symptom, was a variant of the nvidia install issue with the most recent driver and ubuntu version reported at:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-and-nvidia-provided-packages-conflict-breaking-installation/259150

However correcting that situation only made the problem less reproducible. It is still happening.

One other strange thing is when I restart the system, although sometimes it corrects the situation, at other times it will present me with all 3 screens during login, only to, upon login, collapse down to  only 2 screens:
[image]
If I add the 3'rd screen (which is display 1):
[image]
The *Apply* doesn't present me with the corresponding configuration, but rather only 2 screens which, when it reverts becomes a different 2-screen configuration:
[image]

After almost a week of trying all sorts of paths to reinstall Ubuntu so as to get the 3 monitor situation working,  I've got my system running again but I can't be confident that it won't start failing again.  Something is seriously wrong with the latest Ubuntu installation process at least w/regard to [my hardware configuration](https://browser.geekbench.com/v6/cpu/1712133).

```
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +3840+1080 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Successfully made thread 11777 of process 6294 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): connected
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +3840+1080 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+1080 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.

Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +3840+1080 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Successfully made thread 11777 of process 6294 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): connected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 276E8V (DFP-1): 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:32 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): connected
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): Internal TMDS
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Tech Concepts 50S421 (DFP-6): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6371]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-5: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +3840+1080 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+1080 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
Sep 10 11:03:33 jaboweryML rtkit-daemon[1699]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to install an application named displayLink to control multiple displays on Ubuntu, give it a try I guess it will resolve your issue. Here is the link to the **How to Install** page of the application [DisplayLink Installation](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0)

```
wget https://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/Ubuntu/pool/stable/main/all/synaptics-repository-keyring.deb
sudo apt install synaptics-repository-keyring
sudo ln -s /etc/apt/trusted.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install displaylink-driver
reboot
```

Comment: That seems to have improved the situation quite a bit.