# Ubuntu Power off Problem and multi Display Problem

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm encountering some issues:

1-My computer doesn't shut down properly. The screen freezes, and I have to hold the power button for 6 seconds to turn it off.
2-I can't use my external monitor. It worked under Windows, but it's not working now.
My laptop:

MSI GF75 THIN 10UEK-027
Gaming notebook with a 17.3-inch display
Intel® Core™ i7 processor
16 GB RAM
512 GB SSD
Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-34-generic
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Can someone please help with these issues?

Comment: For the second question, try the answer from this: [nvidia-geforce-3 monitor screen lock, which unlocked corrupts configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480213/3-monitor-screen-lock-which-unlocked-corrupts-configuration/1481071#1481071), should solve it